# Spring Data Jpa Many to Many Query

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

entity :

```
 Class User{
    private String id;
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Role> roles;
 }

 Class Role{
   private String id;
   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
   private List<User> users; 

 }
```

UserRepository :

```
 public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Serializable>{

    @Query(" ??? ")

    public User getUser(String id);


}





 public class InMemorySecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;


@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth
            .userDetailsService(username -> { 
                com.casnetvi.cloud.domain.login.User employee = userRepository.findByEmail(username); 
                if (employee == null) {
                    throw new BadCredentialsException("User not found"); 
                }

                List<Role> roles1 = employee.getRoles();

                System.out.println(roles1);
```

Print exception occurred :

### failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.casnetvi.cloud.domain.login.User.roles, could not initialize proxy - no Session"

Want to find out what role(use the getRoles() method to get The Role object) , @Query how to write 
(   Not @Transactional  ,  )

Comment: Can you try with `@Query("select u from User u left join fetch u.roles where u.id=:id")` and adding `@Param("id")` before in the method signature as `getUser(@Param("id") String id)`

Comment: You don't need to add the @Param if the name of the parameters are the same. Also, there is no right or wrong here, but I'd consider adding a 3rd table UserRole of some sort and relate users and roles there. I believe this would make your life easier in the future.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu  , I should see the JPQL query , thank you so much

Comment: @Desorder , your opinion is very useful, I'll try to do a Demo ,thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default fetch type for manyToMany is Lazy.
so in order to get the list of roles you need to do one of the two :
1. execute the configure method inside a transaction.
2. set the relationship with EAGER fetch type:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Role> roles;
```

Comment: Use @JsonManagedReference to prevent JSON in an infinite loop, fetch does not work